# What exactly does mpn_copyi do in the GMP C library?

Tags: c, gmp

I can see from the [GMP official documentation](http://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions.html#index-mpn_005fcopyi-683):

> **void mpn_copyi (mp_limb_t *rp, const mp_limb_t *s1p, mp_size_t n)**
>
> > Copy from {s1p, n} to {rp, n}, increasingly.

> **void mpn_copyd (mp_limb_t *rp, const mp_limb_t *s1p, mp_size_t n)**
>
> > Copy from {s1p, n} to {rp, n}, decreasingly.

However, I don't understand what *increasingly* and *decreasingly* mean in this context. Does *increasingly* mean it will copy all the limbs from 0 to n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the source](http://gmplib.org/), Teabee.

```
void
mpn_copyi (mp_ptr rp, mp_srcptr up, mp_size_t n)
{
  mp_size_t i;

  up += n;
  rp += n;
  for (i = -n; i != 0; i++)
    rp[i] = up[i];
}
```

And decrementing:

```
void
mpn_copyd (mp_ptr rp, mp_srcptr up, mp_size_t n)
{
  mp_size_t i;

  for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    rp[i] = up[i];
}
```

Comment: In which case would you use one and in which case the other?

Comment: I'm not sure actually. They may be different purely to deal with architecture-specific optimisations that are available. The files don't say. I think that if you're not sure which one to use, then they're essentially equivalent for your use case.

Comment: The difference can be very important when the source and the destination overlap, for instance if you are using mpn_copy* to shift the number to the left or right.